# iso date is not converted successfully into time with 12 hour format

Tags: java, android

My code is as shown below:

```
private String getFormattedDate(String date){
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date value = formatter.parse(date);

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM HH:mm a");

        dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        date = dateFormatter.format(value);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        date = "00-00-0000 00:00";
    }

    return date;
}
```

Here what I want to do is , I want to convert `2018-03-19T19:24:41.396Z` into the format `19-03 7:24 PM`, but here it gives me the output `19-03 19:24 PM` . Am I missing anything in my method because of which it is giving the false output?

Comment: note the returned date in the catch block doesn't have the same format than the date in the try block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HH` outputs hour in 0-23 format. You must use `hh` instead.

Answer (score 2):

[SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Capital H   Hour in day (0-23) and Small h  Hour in am/pm (1-12)

Change this line

```
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM HH:mm a");
```

to

```
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM hh:mm a");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
            formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Date value = formatter.parse(date);

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM hh:mm a");

            dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            date = dateFormatter.format(value);
            System.out.println("Date :- "+date);
```